# Fock space for distinguishable particles

Tags: ct.category-theory, mp.mathematical-physics, modules

I am proposing that a category, $\mathcal{C_{\mathcal{Fd}}}$, of Fock Spaces for distinguishable particles is, in fact, a suitably defined tensor product in the category of categories of Modules.  In particular, the category $\mathcal{C_{\mathcal{Fd}}}$ is a suitably defined tensor product of the category $\mathcal{C_{\mathbb{C}}}$, of the category of $\mathbb{C}$-Modules (complex vector spaces) and the category, $\mathcal{C_{\mathbb{N}}}$, of  $\mathbb{N}$-modules.  So,

$\mathcal{C_{\mathcal{Fd}}} = \mathcal{C_{\mathbb{C}}} \otimes \mathcal{C_{\mathbb{N}}}$

I would like to define the tensor product.  To do this, I believe I have to define the "Unit Coherence", "Associativity Coherence" and the "Inverse Law" for the category, $\mathcal{C_{\mathcal{Mod}}}$, of categories of modules.

Does this make sense?

Has anything like this been done?

Edit:
I realize this isn't a Fock space, since it is complex combinations of particle mixes, not tensors of Hilbert spaces.  Does anyone think that the route I am taking could be used to create a Fock Space?  I am thinking of this: $\mathcal{C_{\mathcal{Fd}}} = \mathcal{C_{\mathbb{C}}} \otimes \mathcal{C_{\mathbb{N}}} \otimes \mathcal{C_{\mathbb{C}}}$